# adding a mail contact into AD

Tags: c#, active-directory

I am looking for a bit of guidence on how to create mail contacts in AD.  This is a follow on question from [SO Q#1861336](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1861336/adding-contacts-from-sugarcrm-into-exchange-using-net).

What I am trying to do is add a load of contact objects into an OU in Active Directory.  I've been using the examples on [CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/everythingInAD.aspx), however they only show how to make new user etc.

How do I create a contact using c#?  Is it similar to creating a new user but with different LDAP type attributes?

My plan is to then run the enable-mailcontact cmdlet powershell script to enable Exchange 2010 to see the contact in the GAL.

As you can see by my questions I don't usually deal with c# or Active Directory so any help/pointers would be really useful before I start playing with this loaded gun.

Thanks,

Grant

Answer (score 5, accepted):

it is similar to creating user

just us "contact" instead of "user" as an object

here is a dirty code (not tested)

```
public string CreateContact(string ldapPath, string userName, 
    string userEmail)
{
    string oGUID = string.Empty;
    try
    {            
        string connectionPrefix = "LDAP://" + ldapPath;
        DirectoryEntry dirEntry = new DirectoryEntry(connectionPrefix);
        DirectoryEntry newUser = dirEntry.Children.Add
            ("CN=" + userName, "contact");
        newUser.Properties["DisplayName"].Value = userName;

        //important attributs are
        newUser.Properties["targetAddress"].Value = "SMTP:" + userEmail;
        newUser.Properties["mailNickname"].Value = userName;

        // I'm still trying to figureout what shoud I use here!
        newUser.Properties["showInAddressBook"].Value = ???;

        newUser.CommitChanges();
        oGUID = newUser.Guid.ToString();
        dirEntry.Close();
        newUser.Close();
    }
    catch (System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryServicesCOMException E)
    {
        //DoSomethingwith --> E.Message.ToString();
        //MessageBox.Show(E.Message);    
    }
    return oGUID;
}
```

hope it helps you