# Trouble creating contact in Active Directory C#

Tags: c#, active-directory, exchange-server, contacts

I've been trying to add a contact to Active Directory, so that all the users in it can then see the contacts added. I tried the following code, and I get "Contact created!" message, but when I check in my address book, nothing apears. What am I doing wrong? I'm fairly new to Active Directory and most of the sample code I found, was to add new users. Thank you for your help.

```
public string CreateContact(string name, string mail)
{
    try
    {
        string oGUID = String.Empty;
        DirectoryEntry dirEntry = new DirectoryEntry(path, username, password, AuthenticationTypes.Secure);
        DirectoryEntry newContact = dirEntry.Children.Add("CN=" + name, "contact");
        newContact.Properties["mail"].Value = mail;
        newContact.Properties["msExchHideFromAddressLists"].Value = false;

        newContact.CommitChanges();
        oGUID = newContact.Guid.ToString();
        dirEntry.Close();
        newContact.Close();
        return "Contact created!";

    }
    catch (System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryServicesCOMException e)
    {
        return e.Message.ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [adding a mail contact into AD](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1945483/adding-a-mail-contact-into-ad)

Comment: Shot in the dark here would you not need to call commit changes on the top level dirEntry as well?

Comment: looks like you're missing 2 important attributes 
`newContact.Properties["targetAddress"].Value = "SMTP:" + userEmail;
 newContact.Properties["mailNickname"].Value = userName;` try this awesome link for examples as well http://www.ianatkinson.net/computing/adcsharp.htm

Comment: @Bearcat9425 No.. the commit changes is being called in the proper place

Comment: @MethodMan What is the difference between mail and targetAddress? and between mailNickname and cn? I'm new to Active Directory, so I really don't know the difference.

Comment: When I create a contact using the above code, it doesn't appear in my Address Book, but when I search for it, using c# and a Directory Searcher it's there.

Comment: there is plenty of documentation out there about ActiveDirectory.. start reading some of the documentation as well as look at the link I posted earlier..

Comment: are you closing and re-opening to see if it then appears..?

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into some more info about the attributes. Also, I closed and reopened.